# Sugar ORM как в запросе получить значения больше нуля

Tags: java, android, sql, sugarorm

Собственно, как правильно сделать запрос, чтобы получить значения больше нуля, пробую так, но вылетает с ошибкой

```
List<Database> listPhrase = Database.find(Database.class, "countFavourites = ?", ">0");
```

Comment: Для ознакомления [сравнение ORM для android](https://m.habrahabr.ru/post/281226/)

Comment: Спасибо я это читал. Не думаю что на 1000 строках будет заметна разница по скорости. А по удобству использования разница есть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может так?

```
List<Database> listPhrase = 
    Database.find(Database.class, "countFavourites > ?", "0");
```

Comment: нет, вылетает `android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: countFavourites (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM PHRASEBOOK_DATABASE WHERE countFavourites > ?`

Comment: нашел в чем проблема ответ нашел [здесь](https://github.com/satyan/sugar/issues/137) нужно было название колонки запичывать через нижнее подчеркивание вот так `List<Database> listPhrase = 
    Database.find(Database.class, "count_Favourites > ?", "0");`